# ARM Deployment Error- The request content was invalid and could not be deserialized: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON array

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I had gone through the previous posts similar and not able to find any solution for my situation. So asking again. Please consider.

I am trying to deploy Azure Policy using ARM templates. So, I have created

1- Policy Definition File

2- Policy Parameter File

3- Power Shell script – Run with both Policy and Parameter file as input.

But when I trying to deploy, I am getting the error as attached. The “policyParameters” are being passed as Object type. Seems like the problem resides there. It would be great if you could look at this screen shot attached and advice.

Also the Powershell script out put shows the values expected I think but "ProvisioningState : Failed".

Thanks,

[PolicyFile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHhdn.png)

[Error Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcGLr.png)

[Parameter File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FW7Om.png)

[JSON-part1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjfJf.png)
[JSON-Part2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bY1nz.png)

Comment: Can you please provide your ARM JSON. I guess there's an issue in the deployment section:

e.g.:
"location": "[[parameters('location')]",
It has to be 2 '[' at the beginning:

Please find a sample here:

https://markusmeyer.hashnode.dev/configure-azure-diagnostic-settings-with-azure-policies

Comment: Please see the attachment, I have uploaded  all 3 files now.

Comment: The complete JSON would be nice. The problem might be in the "deployment section"

Comment: Do you need any more input to idenitify this issue? Been siting with this issue for while. :)

Comment: yes, I need more input. The complete JSON would be nice

Comment: attached as 2 files, JSON-Part1 and JSON-part2

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a variable for policyParametars:

```
"variables": {
    "policyParameters": {
        "policyDefinitionId": {
            "defaultValue": "[parameters('policyDefinitionId')]",
            "type": "String"
         },
...
```

This variable has to be passed to your parameters:

```
 "parameters": "[variables('policyParameters')]",
```

You can find a sample here:
[Configure Azure Diagnostic Settings with Azure Policies](https://markusmeyer.hashnode.dev/configure-azure-diagnostic-settings-with-azure-policies)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But my understadning was we must pass the "policyParameters" as an Object. Am I correct? I will give this one a try and let you know the output.

Comment: Can you please make me understand why I should create another variable for policyParameters. And why the Object is not working as expected.

Comment: I did it with a variable because all the parameters have to be passed to 'parameters'.

Comment: I had to specify the object values as below and its worked.

"policyParameters": {
        
        "value": {
            "listOfAllowedLocations":{"value":["West US","East US"]}
        }
    }