Azure pipelines ARM template error: The request content is not valid and could not be deserialized
Hi im trying to rollout a new pipeline using the classic layout approach with ARM. im getting this Error:

The request content is not valid and could not be deserialized: 'Could not find member 'IsReadOnly' on object of type 'ApiConnectionPropertiesDefinition'. Path 'properties.IsReadOnly', line 1, position 64.'

which points to a # in the schema at line one in the ARM template - "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#"
I dont understand why i get that here and not for my other pipelines.

Please show us some code, and/or some screenshots of the classic pipeline.

@Beefybanana https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64042820/arm-deployment-error-the-request-content-was-invalid-and-could-not-be-deseriali >> Make sure you have passed the paramater correctly as per this answer for same error code

bit of a headache to show the code . @SiddheshDesai, are you reffering to the overide template parameters or the pipeline fetch of the parameter folder ?

parameters.json is fine? As in the SO answer above -  had to specify the object values as below and its worked. "policyParameters": { "value": { "listOfAllowedLocations":{"value":["West US","East US"]} } } Adding values to the parameter property has resolved the issue. Also, your logic of overriding template parameter with another value will work, But make sure if you are using string parameter the override parameter value should also be string "abs" do not use integer 123

Agree with @SiddheshDesai. Please review the ARM template and the parameters file to ensure they are correctly formatted and all required properties are included. Please check same error on ticket.

@Beefybanana If you can tell me which resource you are deploying via ARM Template, I can share you the ARM Template deployment with code via devops as an answer

In order to resolve this error, Make sure you have passed some Default value in your parameter script like below:-
My ARM template where I have added existing APIConnection of Logic App:-
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "logicAppName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "myLogicApp",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name of the Logic App."
      }
    },
    "location": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "centralus",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Location for all resources."
      }
    },
    "connectionName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "myApiConnection",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name of the API connection."
      }
    },
    "apiName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "azureappservice",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name of the API to connect with."
      }
    },
    "apiUrl": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "https://api.example.com",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Base URL of the API to connect with."
      }
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Logic/workflows",
      "apiVersion": "2017-07-01",
      "name": "[parameters('logicAppName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "properties": {
        "definition": {
          "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
          "actions": {
            "HTTP": {
              "inputs": {
                "method": "GET",
                "uri": "[parameters('apiUrl')]"
              },
              "runAfter": {},
              "type": "Http"
            }
          },
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
          "outputs": {},
          "parameters": {},
          "triggers": {
            "Recurrence": {
              "recurrence": {
                "frequency": "Minute",
                "interval": 15
              },
              "type": "Recurrence"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/connections",
      "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
      "name": "[parameters('connectionName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "properties": {
        "displayName": "[parameters('connectionName')]",
        "api": {
          "id": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/', parameters('location'), '/managedApis/', parameters('apiName'))]"
        },
        "customParameterValues": {}
      }
    }
  ]
}

In the above code azureappservice is the existing  APIConnection and myApiConnection is the new API connection that needs to be deployed.
Output:-

My Logic app got deployed successfully with new APIConnection and using Existing API connection:-

Reference:-
azure - ARM Deployment Error- The request content was invalid and could not be deserialized: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON array - Stack Overflow
